# executable jar nor working - this contains applet

Tags: executable-jar

HI,

I have written a Applet class which acts as Main class for jar. When I run the code from eclipse, it runs fine.. But from Desktop (Jar) does not work. Any idea?

Should main method explicitly call init() method? I tried that but it does not work.

Any help is appreciated.

thanks

Comment: When you said "it does not work", what happens? Do you get an error, if so, what is the error?

Answer (score 0):

Did you define your manifest in the jar?

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#JAR%20Manifest

Comment: Thanks! I made it work. What I had to do is, create JFrame in main method and add this applet into that.

Comment: Excellent! I'm going to try to not sound greedy, because this is more for you than it is for me. You know when you go on a date, it goes better if you get the girl flowers? Here on SO, upvotes and accepted answers are our flowers :-). After a certain amount of time, you'll get a X% accepted under your name, which shows how often you accept answers. If that's high (I actually keep mine at100%) you're more likely to get people to help you with your questions.

Answer (score 0):

You should create an html file with an applet tag containing information about your applet
The tag contents should be as below. See the [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/html.html)

```
<applet code = 'com.example.MyApplet' 
archive = 'MyApplet.jar', 
width = 300, 
height = 300 />
```